# How to position triggered segue as popover - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, positioning, popover

I have created a popover using triggered segue (picture below) in Storyboard. When i click on the button the popover appears. But the position of the popover is being changed as per the window size of my application. Is there any way that i could specify a fixed position for the popover triggered segue.

[image]